# What does she say in this dialogue?

Tags: translation, names, anime

What does the character "Historia" say in the dialogue in minute 1:41 of [this video](http://www.animeyt.tv/ver/shingeki-no-kyojin-2-6-sub-espanol)? I can only understand the first part but not the last words. She starts saying

> Ymir... watashi no namae ... Historia ...

Does she say her last name or something? I would have expected she says

> Historia desu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She says

> 私の名前ヒストリアって言うの
>   My name is Historia

- って is used as a colloquial of と
- の is part of feminine speech (declarative) and softens と言う
- と言う can also be used in polite language

  > 私の名前はヒストリアです = 私はヒストリアと言います

  but the situation isn't quite right for formal introductions (you shouldn't have expected です here)

Comment: so the literal translation would be something like  "My name Historia it is called" ? That's a polite form of introducing yourself? or I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: 私の名前ヒストリアっていうの is a natural way of saying "My name is Historia". Literally I would go for something like "My name is called Historia". It's not polite. The two ways 私はヒストリアっていうの and 私の名前はヒストリア(なの) are like "I'm called Historia" and "My name is Historia". I was just saying that と言います is common also in polite speech (because you were talking about です).